# Why isn't the modifier icon appearing when an object is selected?

Tags: modifiers

I'm brand new to Blender, and am attempting to subtract one object from another. Simple, I know, and all I have read says to use the modifier tool, which is a wrench.  However, I can not find this wrench.  [image]

attached is a screen shot of my toolbar showing where I thought the wrench should be.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I thank you kindly,
Matt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Metaball objects cannot have modifiers applied to them. Once an object that can have a modifier applied to it (like a mesh or a curve) is selected the wrench icon will appear.

Objects that can have modifiers added to them are:

- Meshes
- Curves
- Surfaces
- Text
- Lattices

Comment: Hi Ray, How do I know what is or isn't meta?  I have imported an obj. file from a simple 3D scan.  Would that be Meta?

Comment: -sigh-  I think I just figured it out by choosing Model Mesh as opposed to MBall.   Cheers Ray

Comment: @MJACKSONstudios A metaball is a specific type of object in blender, so yes if you import as a mesh that will be fine. If this answer has helped you then you can mark it as 'Accepted' by clicking the 'tick' icon next to my answer. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers