# modifier tab missing

Tags: modifiers

I'm using Blender 2.78 on OSX and I'm trying to subtract one cuboid from another but no luck. I am in object mode and have selected one of them but modifiers tab is missing. (I really miss help search the way it works in most tools on mac)
[image: a screenshot]

Comment: Your object is an empty... it has no geometry and no modifiers, just a shape.

Comment: You can't add a modifier to an empty. Please see related answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24267/why-isnt-the-modifier-icon-appearing-when-an-object-is-selected

Comment: Thank you @lemon. Is there any way to "fulfil" it?

Comment: Thank you @Paul Gonet. This can definitely be marked as duplicate 

Comment: An empty is a particular object type and cannot be converted to a mesh. You should add/create a cube instead