# Blender 2.8 Mac OS , modifiers tab missing?

Tags: versions

Hi I was using previous versions of 2.8 and now version available today, does not show the modifier tab on the right. I might get lost on UI updates?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75625/modifier-tab-missing

Answer (score 0):

Just realised that they will appear when I have a mesh in my scene. Thanks