# I can't find the modifiers tab in 2.8

Tags: modifiers

It was previously showing on screen but now I can't find it, even when the object with the subdivision surface modifier is selected. I have managed to apply a modifier via searching the modifier but I'm unable to modify its properties
.
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143923/blender-2-8-mac-os-modifiers-tab-missing https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24267/why-isnt-the-modifier-icon-appearing-when-an-object-is-selected

Answer (score 4):

you need to select an object that can have modifiers applyed onto it, and then on the right on the properties panel under the wrench tab.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have accidentally pinned the Properties Editor when you had a different item selected. So now, even though you clearly have a mesh selected, you don't see the Modifiers, as the properties editor shows you information about something else.

Click the *PIN* needle to unpin the editor, then everything should be back to normal:

[image]